# Microsoft Access 97, can i assign a background image to a cell?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I'm trying to work with a very old project, i can't update the project to a newer access version due a customer decision. I can't also migrate the project to another technology... So i have reinstalled an old office 97 version and i'm trying to edit the project in this way. I need to apply a custom background image to the cell of my tabular form view. The images are 4 and they will loaded or not due a value that my query extract from db. In a meta-language i will write something like this:

```
if(condition==1){ load image 1 }
else if (condition==2){ load image 2}
else{ load image 3}
```

How i can achive this results? It is possible in Access 97?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

In Access, an image requires the picture control for display (or a third party control). You might be able to overlay this with a textbox (what you call a cell) having a transparent background, but the picture underneath will probably vanish when the textbox gets focus.